# Is it possible to write a speech-recognition engine from scratch?

Tags: math, speech-recognition, speech

Using some existing math libraries, though. The point is, that there is literally no research in this field in my language (Georgian). Is that possible? How long would I take? I know that this also depends on the skills, but still?

Answer (score 4):

Also answered at

[Speech to text conversion for non-english language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045889/speech-to-text-conversion-for-non-english-language)

> Is it possible to write a speech-recognition engine from scratch?

You do not need to write engine from scratch, there are many engines already available, you can just pick one like CMUSphinx

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

If you just interested in supporting Georgian, it's just a task to train Georgian model, you do not need to implement engine itself. Speech recognition engines do not depend on langauge.

> The point is, that there is literally no research in this field in my language (Georgian).

Luckily there is a lot in English.

> How long would I take?

It takes about a month of single man work to create a database for a new language for CMUSphinx. For more details see the documentation:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial (Tutorial)

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam (Acoustic model training tutorial chapter)

Comment: Well... I down voted this originally because I did not like how you side skirted the original question by saying "just use one already made". However it appears that you answered a very similar question in a much better manner (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37860/build-automatic-speech-recognition-asr-from-scratch). Thank you for feeding my Amazon book buying addiction.